# UIStoryboardPopoverSegue dismiss when toolbar button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

First of all, I've found a similar question but it does not do the exact same thing I want: [UIStoryboardPopoverSegue opening multiple windows on button touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758837/uistoryboardpopoversegue-opening-multiple-windows-on-button-touch)

I have a tool bar with a button that presents a popOver, all wired up with the storyboard.

The problem is that each time I press a button, a new popOver comes up, over the previous one.

In the other question, they suggest this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]){
        // Dismiss current popover, set new popover
        [currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        currentPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    }
}
```

But what it does is, when you press the button, it dismisses the previous popOver (if there's one) and continues with the segue to show a new popOver.

What I want to do is for the button to act as a toggle, meaning that it dismisses the popOver if there's one (not showing a new one) and shows a popOver if there's not one already.

That, by the way, is how it used to work for me without the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225589/ios-create-an-popover-view-using-storyboard/8867830#8867830) answers your question.  Basically you change the action of the button each time it's pressed to either display or dismiss the popover.