# iOS - Create an Popover View using StoryBoard

Tags: ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller, xcode4.2, storyboard

Hi there, Now I'm trying to create a Pop-OverView using an Xcode
storyboard. Firstly, I have

```
rootViewController, UIViewController, and UITableViewController
```

I want the UIView to act as a page flip and the UITableView will show popOver under the navigationBar item controller.

For the UITableView, I want to make a Pop-Over under NavigationBar controller. The problem is, when I touch the Navigation item to show the UITableViewController, it shows correctly, but when I try to close the Pop-Over View, it won't close. And then, the navigation item doesn't work well. It shows multiple instances of popOverView when I touch it multiple times.

This doesn't seem to make sense to me. Can anyone help me out or tell me where to find documentation / tutorials on this?

UPDATE:

For the UIPopOverController, it seems to work well now, but it is still bugging me when I touch a Navigation Item multiple times. It will show multiple instances of PopOver. How can I handle it, so it will show only one instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and mostly found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758837/uistoryboardpopoversegue-opening-multiple-windows-on-button-touch).  Basically you change the action of the button each time it's pressed to either display or dismiss the popover.  Here's the code I ended up with:

```
@interface FilterTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    UIPopoverController *editPopover;
    id saveEditSender;
    id saveEditTarget;
    SEL saveEditAction;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditFilterSegue"]){
        // Save the edit button's info so we can restore it
        saveEditAction = [sender action];
        saveEditTarget = [sender target];
        saveEditSender = sender;

        // Change the edit button's target to us, and its action to dismiss the popover
        [sender setAction:@selector(dismissPopover:)];
        [sender setTarget:self];

        // Save the popover controller and set ourselves as the its delegate so we can
        // restore the button action when this popover is dismissed (this happens when the popover
        // is dismissed by tapping outside the view, not by tapping the edit button again)
        editPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        editPopover.delegate = (id <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>)self;
    }
}

-(void)dismissPopover:(id)sender
{
    // Restore the buttons actions before we dismiss the popover
    [saveEditSender setAction:saveEditAction];
    [saveEditSender setTarget:saveEditTarget];
    [editPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    // A tap occurred outside of the popover.
    // Restore the button actions before its dismissed.
    [saveEditSender setAction:saveEditAction];
    [saveEditSender setTarget:saveEditTarget];

    return YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Before we navigate away from this view (the back button was pressed)
    // remove the edit popover (if it exists).
    [self dismissPopover:saveEditSender];
}
```

Comment: I'd call this workaround overly complicated, but that's mostly a matter of taste. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238581/957768) has my preferred workaround, and there are a few more in the other answers to the same question.

Comment: @rickster I agree, that looks a lot simpler, I'll try that next time.