# How to dismiss popovers in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, xcode4.2

I have a **PatientTableViewController** in the master side of the iPad that has a button for Adding a new patient. It transitions to this **NewPatientViewController** via a *popover segue*.

In the **NewPatientViewController** I have a Done button that delegates back to the **PatientTableViewController**:

```
- (void)newPatientViewController:(NewPatientViewController *)sender withZipCode:(NSNumber *)zipCode andFirstName:(NSString *)firstName andLastName:(NSString *)lastName
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [sender dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [sender dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

None of the methods I tried above work. However, if I use a Modal segue, everything works fine. Wat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figure it out with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225589/ios-create-an-popover-view-using-storyboard)

Basically, you need to have a variable keep track of the segue (which you need to cast into a **UIStoryboardPopoverSegue**) and little more weirdness.

I wrote a [blog post](http://readncode.com/blog/how-to-dismiss-popovers-in-ios/) describing the solution in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try `dismissPopoverAnimated:` on UIPopoverController class?

Comment: Thanks man. I tried that but did not know on which property to call it. I finally stumbled on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225589/ios-create-an-popover-view-using-storyboard) which helped me figure it out.

Comment: I haven't worked with storyboards yet, so I was just shooting in the dark.