# Dismiss the popover view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a root view controller in which I load a sub view that contains three buttons. When I touch one of them a popover is shown. The popover contains an image view and a bar with a Done button. I want to dismiss this popover when the Done button is touched. To accomplish this I am using this code

```
- (IBAction)btnDone:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

        [APPDELEGATE.parkDetail. popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   // [APPDELEGATE.parkDetail.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES ];


}
```

and the popover is presented like this

```
- (IBAction)btnParkMap:(id)sender {
       [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        parkMap * v = [[parkMap alloc]initWithNibName:@"parkMap" bundle:nil];
        v.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(350, 300);
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:v];
               CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(self.btnShowPopover.frame.origin.x+330,
                                    self.btnShowPopover.frame.origin.y+170,
                                    self.btnShowPopover.frame.size.width,
                                    self.btnShowPopover.frame.size.height);


        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
          }
}
```

Comment: Do you have done button on parkMap class right?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or try @nirav's ans

Answer (score 1):

Try to write below code

```
[yourPopOverobject dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Let me know whether it is working or not..

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: it should work man...tell me how you have present the popover controller..write some code...

Comment: my view become Disappear but the popover black frame remains there

Comment: ok,,just remove that code..  [self.view removeFromSuperview]; and then check what happen...let me know

Comment: i have posted another code ,,try that one , i have put one delegate method in that code.put breakpoint in that method and let me know

Answer (score 1):

The PopUpOver can beswitch off the default contextual menu of UIWebView. This is easy because we only need to set the CSS property “-webkit-touch-callout” to “none” for the body element of the web page. We can do this using JavaScript in the UIWebView delegate method “webViewDidFinishLoad:”…

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (IBAction)btnDone:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check below code...

```
if ([popoverobject isPopoverVisible]) {
   [popoverobject dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   [popoverobject release];
}
```

}

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPopoverController delegate

-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
 //if (popoverController == popoverobject) {
    [popoverobject release];
 //  }
}

- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

   NSLog(@\"popover about to be dismissed\");
   return YES;
  }
```

let me know is it working or not...

Comment: in the same class where you want to dismiss the popover controller

Comment: i have told you everything that i know man...i think you have miss some code but you are not finding that..check your code again..

Comment: http://www.readncode.com/blog/how-to-dismiss-popovers-in-ios/          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656348/ios-how-to-dismiss-popovers                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253878/how-to-dismiss-popovers-in-ios-5 may be this links help you..try it